# How to make a find,update,replace in Windows (Powershell,Findstr)

Tags: windows, shell, powershell

What I want : 
open a file, find a match with a regex,increment the match,replace the match in text,save the file.

Is it possible to do this with Powershell or the FINDSTR command ?

Comment: This would be a 1 liner in Perl, FWIW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 "*original file*"
 gc matchtest.txt

 $match_pat = "^(Match\stext\s)(\d+)"
 $newfile = @()
 gc matchtest.txt |% {
 if ($_ -match $match_pat) {

     $incr =  1 + $matches[2]
     $newfile += $_ -replace $match_pat,($matches[1] + $incr)
     }
   else {$newfile += $_}
  }

  $newfile | out-file matchtest.txt -force

  "`n*new file*"
  gc matchtest.txt

 *original file*
 Not match 121
 Match text 127
 Not match 123

 *new file*
 Not match 121
 Match text 128
 Not match 123
```